# Django: How to pass user to models.py

Tags: python, django

I am writing an application where I want to show a list of courses and for each course, a progress bar with the percentage of lessons completed.

I am running the logic to calculate this percentage in the models with a property called **progress** created for the model *Course*:

**models.py**

```
class Course(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    allowed_memberships = models.ManyToManyField(Membership)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("courses:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
        
    @property    
    def lessons(self):
        return self.lesson_set.all().order_by('position')

    @property
    def progress(self):
        completed = lessonsCompleted.objects.filter(course_id=self.id)
        return int(completed.count() / self.lessons.count() * 100)
```

I would need to take into account who is logged in currently in order to show the progress for that user in each of the courses.

I don't know how to pass the user to my models.py so I can take that user into the algorithm and filter only the lessons completed by that user in order to calculate the progress completed on each course.

If I had the user I could add that parameter to the filter and get the progress for that user for each course. Here:

```
completed = lessonsCompleted.objects.filter(course_id=self.id, user_id=<somehow get user id of user logged in here>)
```

Here is the template where I call the progress property to show a progress bar for each course:

**template:**

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ object.title }}</a></h5>
        <div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-xlarge">
            <div class="w3-container w3-blue w3-round-xlarge" id="progress-{{ object.slug }}" style="width:{{ object.progress }}%">{{ object.progress }}%</div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

One more piece of data is that I am using a class based view:

**views.py**

```
class CourseListView(ListView):
    model = Course
```

And here is how it looks:
[my page showing courses and progress of each one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw7zl.jpg)

I am learning, this is an educational project, any help would be very much appreciated, I got really stuck here. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Through a parameter. Models are supposed to be request-unaware. You can specify this in your view. Here it would also be better to use `.annotate(..)` than a method/property, since this can calculate the progress in "bulk".

Comment: user = models.ForeignKey('User' on_delete=models.CASCADE, ) you can use this and refer to user via a foreign key

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem, do you mean I should use a regular view, not a class based view, and build it to use the user via the request and then do the logic there instead of in my models.py? Many thanks

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have followed my interpretation of your advice and I am building my view from scratch as a function and not as a class based view. However I got stacked at the point where I am trying to pass an object with the *progress* property to my template and it is not working. Here is the question I posted about this other problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64134762/how-to-pass-object-properties-from-view-to-template-in-django